# How to dynamically instantiate a class whos type is decided at runtime

Tags: java

Lets assume I have three classes: `class B`, `class C`, and `class D`. All three of these classes are children of `class A`.

I don't know which child of class a will need to be instanciated at runtime. I have looked into Class.forName() and its companion function, newInstance(), but when I try and actually use them, I generate  `incompatible types` errors. This makes sense, as an Object can't be directly converted into my custom classes.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
 public A build(String className, int[] properties) {
     Class clasz = Class.forName(className);
     A a = clasz.newInstance();
     a.setProperties(properties);
     return a;
 }
```

My code assumes that className will only ever contain values that are children of Class A. In the examples I've seen, the authors have been casting the result of newInstance() to the class they want it to be. That said, I can't do this as I don't know which class I'm instantiating into.

I feel like I may be missing something critical about the purpose and functions of these methods. Please help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thank you.

Comment: if they are children of `A`, you should be able to cast to it : `A a = (A)clasz.newInstance();`

Comment: and I assume `build` returns `A`, not `Effect` (whatever that is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should cast to and return `A`:

```java
public A build(String className, int[] properties) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> clasz = Class.forName(className);
    A a = (A)clasz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    a.setProperties(properties);
    return a;
}
```

See a demo [here](https://www.codiva.io/p/539a8f8b-5819-4a41-83d6-d0f28ec3076e).

Also note that you should supply a type argument in the declaration of `clasz` (`Class<?> clasz`) to avoid a warning. And the `newInstance()` method in `java.lang.Class` is deprecated since version 9. From [the Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--):

> **Deprecated.** *This method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) InvocationTargetException.*
>
> *The call*
>
> `clazz.newInstance()`
>
> *can be replaced by*
>
> `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Comment: If I cast to A on an object built from a forName() on Class C, can I still call methods that are exclusively found in Class C?

Comment: @Aaron, if you need to call methods that are not defined in A but in C, you need to cast to C.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically cast it that way? If not, using an abstract function declared in Class A should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have this classes:

```
public class A {}
public class B extends A {}
public class C extends B {}
```

Examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class) instanceof C); // True
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class) instanceof B); // True
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class) instanceof A); // True
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class.getName()) instanceof C); // True
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class.getName()) instanceof B); // True
    System.out.println(getInstance(C.class.getName()) instanceof A); // True
}

public static <T extends A> T getInstance(Class<T> tClass) throws Exception {
    Constructor<T> constructor = tClass.getConstructor();
    return constructor.newInstance();
}

public static Object getInstance(String className) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
    return constructor.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Why is `System.out.println(getInstance(C.class) instanceof B);` true?

Comment: My mistake, I am using the terms super and sub. I update a little bit different list of classes. But you will be able to extract the answer.